# I couldn't use the Autocomplete from material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, material-ui, npm-install

```js
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
```

I have used the import like above. I am getting the below error

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Autocomplete'
```

My dependencies are like

```json
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
"@material-ui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.30",
```

I think the problems is in the @material-ui/lab/Autocomplete.js file

The code is

```js
import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/extends";
import * as React from 'react';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/core/Autocomplete';
import { jsx as _jsx } from "react/jsx-runtime";
let warnedOnce = false;
/**
 * @ignore - do not document.
 */

export default /*#__PURE__*/React.forwardRef(function DeprecatedAutocomplete(props, ref) {
  if (!warnedOnce) {
    console.warn(['Material-UI: The Autocomplete component was moved from the lab to the core.', '', "You should use `import { Autocomplete } from '@material-ui/core'`", "or `import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/core/Autocomplete'`"].join('\n'));
    warnedOnce = true;
  }

  return /*#__PURE__*/_jsx(Autocomplete, _extends({
    ref: ref
  }, props));
});
```

And '@material-ui/core/Autocomplete' doesn't exist.

Comment: "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.49" this is the version I am working on and works perfectly fine.. try to install  like this npm i @material-ui/lab@4.0.0-alpha.49

Comment: Also the error says Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/Autocomplete'
So make sure you did not added this import in some other files, it should be  => import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

Comment: I used this version "4.0.0-alpha.49" now it is working fine. Thank you Vaibhav